# Cassandra custom data type

Tags: java, cassandra, data-modeling, custom-data-type

is it possiable to write and read custom data type in cassandra 2.1. I've found  [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/custom-cassandra-data-types) article in the web. But cassandras' 2.1  `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.class` has different interface.
I know that is possiable to *CREATE TYPE* using query inside, according to [this](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/introducing-datastax-java-driver-2-1/) article. But I have complex class

```
public class Record implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7508863944692581230L;

private final UUID id;
private final Map<String, String> values;
private final Set<String> set;
```

`
Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: have you seen this link? https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/custom_codecs/